# How to install mailgun in PHP?

Tags: php, mailgun

This is how I install mailgun on a VM that runs PHP:

```
# Install Composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
# Add Mailgun as a dependency
php composer.phar require mailgun/mailgun-php:~2.0
# Add Guzzle 6 as a dependency
php composer.phar require php-http/guzzle6-adapter:^1.1.1
```

But when I load a page with this content:

```
<?php 

require_once('/app/mailgun-php/vendor/autoload.php');

echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();

ini_set('display_errors' , 'On');

$client = new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client();

$mailgun = new \Mailgun\Mailgun('123', $client);

# use Mailgun\Mailgun;

?>
```

I get the following error:

```
Current PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Fatal error: Class 'Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client' not found in /app/sign-in.php on line 5
```

What is wrong with the installation?

Comment: You need to include the required files or use an autoloader

Comment: Can you please show me how? I am not familiar with PHP.

Comment: No need to be familiar with php. Being able to RTFM might help though https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: you need to use this command: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php and include whichever php files are needed by that component

Comment: `composer require...` has created a `composer.json` and a `vendor/` directory, which contains the necessary `vendor/autoload.php` file you must then `require` in your application as mentioned in Roland's comment.

Comment: I did what Martin said bellow, after fixing the file path. However, when I do `use Mailgun\Mailgun;` just right after, I get an empty HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Composer autoloader so PHP knows where the Mailgun `Client` class actually is:

```
<?php 
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
ini_set('display_errors' , 'On');
$client = new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I altered the path a little bit now PHP does not complain. However, when I do `use Mailgun\Mailgun;`, then I get an empty html page. Note that, the above `use` is required according to the documentation: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php How can I debug this error?